# Disable the "Notification Center" on iPad (phonegap) application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, cordova

Is there any way to remove the swipe event that pulls in the notification center from the top of the ipad when developing an ipad app? If there is an easy way in PhoneGap, that would be best, if not - I can manually implement any Objective-C solution.

The app is already in full screen, and there are some gestures that including swiping at the top. These iPads are distributed to the sales force of this company, and they want that feature (top swipe notification center) disabled.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your app is in fullscreen mode, Notification Center switches to a two-swipe system: swipe once to bring up a little handle, and swipe down on the handle to bring up Notification Center. This should avoid most interference.

Other than that, there's no public way to disable this gesture.

Comment: I have noticed a few full screen apps that let you do a two finger swipe from the top to get out of full screen, keynote for example does this. The pull chain doesn't come down at all in this case... I wonder how they are doing it...

Comment: Are you using UIGestureRecognizer? I haven't tried but that would be my first guess....

Comment: I am not - using a phonegap application right now. This basically consists of a UIWebView that loads JS/HTML/CSS as the 'application.' I do, however, have access to the iOS API's if a solution is discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. At least not without a jailbroken phone. Notification Center is built into the OS and cannot be disabled by third party apps. As @jtbandes pointed out, their is the "handle" option, but there is no way to completely disable the functionality.